Health status depending on liveness or readiness
Let's say I got a service which needs to do some work on startup. So it is beginning in state Startable, goes on to Starting, then Ready, Stopping, and Startable again.
These states are mapped to HealthStatuses as follows:



State
HealthStatus




Startable
Unhealthy


Starting
Degraded


Ready
Healthy


Stopping
Degraded



When the environment performs a liveness check, I would like the service presented as live when it is degraded (at least I interpret the term as that). When it comes to whether or not the service is ready to serve, then I would only answer that positively when the HealthStatus is Healthy. Is there a way to implement that or am I over-interpreting the API?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

It is possible to customize the health check output report, all you need to do is use a ResponseWriter in HealthCheckOptions:
app.MapHealthChecks("/healthz", new HealthCheckOptions
{
    ResponseWriter = WriteResponse
});

//----------------------------

private static async Task WriteResponse(HttpContext context, HealthReport report)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        HealthCheckResponse value = new HealthCheckResponse
        {
            // here you can set Status to whatever you want based on entries status
            Status = (report.Entries.Any() && report.Entries.All(x => x.Value.Status == HealthStatus.Degraded) ? HealthStatus.Unhealthy : report.Status).ToString(),
            Checks = report.Entries.Select((KeyValuePair<string, HealthReportEntry> x) => new HealthCheck
            {
                Componenet = x.Key,
                Status = x.Value.Status.ToString(),
                Description = x.Value.Description,
                Duration = x.Value.Duration
            }),
            Duration = report.TotalDuration
        };
        if (value.Status == HealthStatus.Unhealthy.ToString())
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
    }

For more detailed info please read the doc as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-8.0#customize-output

I'm not sure if I fully understood your question.
I suggest you not only do a liveness probe but also a startup probe. Configure them to different endpoints and implement them slightly different.
Once the startup probes returns healthy for the first time, it is no longer called but from then on the livenessprobe is called.
